# How to set focus on font awesome icon mapped to radio button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap in an ASP.NET MVC application. In one page I want to show a Grid or List view when a user click on the relevant icon.  To do that, I'm using radio buttons and it does show based on user selection.

But the problem is that it always focuses on the Grid icon, even if it fires list mode.

**Here's My Code**:

```html
<div class="row" >
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
    <form class="pull-left">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary  active" title="Show as a Grid" >
          <i class="fa fa-table"></i>
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.Context.ViewMode, "grid",
                  new { name = "viewmode", @class = "",
                        onchange = "setLocation('?viewmode=grid');" })
          Grid
        </label>

        <label class="btn btn-primary" title="Show as a List" >
          <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
          @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.PagingFilteringContext.ViewMode, "list", 
                  new { name = "viewmode", @class = "", 
                        onchange = "setLocation('?viewmode=list');" }) 
          List
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="show-content">

  @if (Model.Context.ViewMode == "grid")
  {
    <label>Grid content here...</label>
  }
  else
  {
    <label>List content here...</label>
  }

</div>
```

```js
// set visibility between icons

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Context_ViewMode").on('click', function () {
    ToggleRadioButtons("#Context_ViewMode", $(this));
  });
});

function ToggleRadioButtons(groupName, current) {
  var chk = $(groupName + " .fa-table");
  $(chk).removeClass('fa-table').addClass('fa-list');
  $(current).find(">:first-child").removeClass('fa-list');
  $(current).find(">:first-child").addClass('fa-table');
}
```

But it didn't set focus on List icon when clicked. Any ideas?

**Edit:**

I managed to get event firing work, but it doesn’t stay as selected if ‘List’ selected, change back to ‘Grid’ highlighted(active) after loading correct ‘List’ result from the server.

Summary of changes:

1. Added new class ‘fawsm-radiobutton’ for both labels
2. Added new class ‘nonactive’ for label list
3. Changed the JavaScript to add remove 'active' and 'notactive'

**Here’s My Code changes:**

```
<label class="fawsm-radiobutton btn btn-primary  active" title="Show as a Grid" >
  <i class="fa fa-table"></i>
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.Context.ViewMode, "grid",
              new { name = "viewmode", @class = "",
                    onchange = "setLocation('?viewmode=grid');" })
      Grid
 </label>

 <label class="fawsm-radiobutton btn btn-primary notactive" title="Show as a List" >
   <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
   @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.PagingFilteringContext.ViewMode, "list", 
              new { name = "viewmode", @class = "", 
                    onchange = "setLocation('?viewmode=list');" }) 
      List
 </label>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#Context_ViewMode>.fawsm-radiobutton").on('change', function () {
  ToggleRadioButtons("#Context_ViewMode", $(this));
 });
});

function ToggleRadioButtons(groupName, current) {
 var chk = $(groupName + " .fawsm-radiobutton.active");
 $(chk).removeClass('active’).addClass('notactive');
 $(current).find(">:first-child").removeClass('notactive');
 $(current).find(">:first-child").addClass('active');
}
```

When I use developer tool(F12) on the browser it shows the removal and addition of ‘active’ and ‘notactive’ classes to lable.  But after loading List items from the server it revert back to original ‘Grid’ icon in active mode. 
So I guess that when the browser renders

```
@if (Model.Context.ViewMode == "grid")
{}
else{}
```

section I need to notify client to do the above changes to the label classes. I do not know how to do it. Do I need to use something like AJAX?

Comment: @KyleMit, As I said in the original post it does work as the functionality when user click, but the focus to correct icon doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) method.

Comment: How do I use it? Should I use .focus() function instead of .on('click', function () ?

Comment: when you are ready to set focus, $('yertarget').focus(); Obviously replace 'yertarget' with a selector for what you want focused.

Comment: I added ids to both labels, and added $('#list').focus(); to the JavaScript. But no luck, same problem.